# Does Google Analytics Tracking for Flash works in packaged air application for IOS?

Tags: ios, air, google-analytics

I'm building an air application (using adt packager) for iPad. I would like tracking some informations in my app so is it possible to embed Google Analytics library for Flash (.swc) in my packaged app ?
otherwise are there alternatives ways ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. I have it running in my pure AS3 AIR project for mobile.

See http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/ there is a swc you can use there.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Currently, Flash tracking is available for any Flash content embedded in a web page. Tracking of data sent from Adobe Air, Shockwave, or via the Flash IDE (e.g. using Test Movie) is not supported at this time.

got this from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/flashTrackingIntro

Answer (score 2):

I am having better luck with this alternative native extension (ANE) for iOS and Android:
https://github.com/alebianco/ANE-Google-Analytics

GAForFlash (http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/) v1.0.1.319 did work for me when compiling with AIR and running in ADL on Windows, but seems to work intermittently when compiling and running it on an Android or iOS device. The visual debug feedback reports it always sending correctly, but half the time GA never receives the data.

Both solutions can send both pageViews and events, but neither (currently) works with the new mobile app GA profiles so you need to use a classic web profile.

Comment: The native extension is the way to go if you want to use the application profile since it now supports this.